# DELETE record in a row in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was trying to delete a record on my Database. So basically I created a table that contains all of my records. Now what I need to do is when I click on the "DELETE" link it would delete the record selected row.

Here's what it looks like:

So basically I have 3 pages here. 
1. page.php
2. add.php
3. delete.php

Here's my page.php file:

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>date</th>
        <th>delete</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php 
            foreach($emails as $mail){ ?>
            <td><?php echo $mail['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $mail['date']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<a href='delete.php?id=". $mail['id']. "'>DELETE</a>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php } ?>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's my add.php file:

```
<?php
    require("new-connection.php");

    session_start();

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(empty($_POST['email']) AND (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false))
     {
          $_SESSION['message'] = "email cannot be blank";
     }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO email_tbl (email, date)
              VALUES('$email', NOW())";       

    $insertEmail = run_mysql_query($query);


    if(run_mysql_query($query))
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "New RECORD has been added correctly!";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "Failed to add new Interest"; 
    }

    }


    header('Location: email.php');




?>
```

Here's my delete.php file so far:

```
<?php
    require("new-connection.php");

    session_start();


    $query = "DELETE FROM email_tbl
            WHERE id={id} LIMIT 1";       

    $deleteEmail = run_mysql_query($query);


    if(run_mysql_query($query))
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "RECORD has been DELETED correctly!";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "Failed to DELETE RECORD"; 
    }



    header('Location: email.php');




?>
```

So now when I click the delete link it must delete the button real time. Any idea?

Comment: use a button instead and wrap each in a form with a hidden field for the id, or you can use an iframe and the $_GET or ajax even.  No way this  id={id}  works.

Comment: What do you mean real time, without reloading the page?

Comment: what is this? run_mysql_query()

Answer (score 4):

Modify your delete.php to retrieve the url parameter:

```
<?php
    require("new-connection.php");
    session_start();

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $query = "DELETE FROM email_tbl
            WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";       

    $deleteEmail = run_mysql_query($query);


    if($deleteEmail)
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "RECORD has been DELETED correctly!";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] .= "Failed to DELETE RECORD"; 
    }

    header('Location: email.php');
?>
```

As for your add.php, you are using this:

```
$insertEmail = run_mysql_query($query);

    if(run_mysql_query($query))
```

You should change it to this:

```
$insertEmail = run_mysql_query($query);


    if($insertEmail)
```

What you are doing right now is you are executing the query twice by calling run_mysql_query twice. This should fix it

Comment: Wow thanks! @MatchesMalone. Any idea why my INSERT code returns 2 record at the same time? Basically when I put the email on the input and click submit it automatically add two rows with the same record and duplicating what I am inserting????? Any idea whats causing this????

Comment: Maybe it's because you call 2 times run_mysql_query

Comment: I am referring to the add.php btw. :) it was inserting two records.

Comment: After you define the query you call $deleteEmail = run_mysql_query($query); and in the if statement you should use the $deleteEmail variable

Comment: AWESOME! hahahahah. THANKS!

Comment: See modified answer, OP

Answer (score 1):

Sense when what `run_mysql_query` a function in php?

http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=run_mysql_query&scope=quickref

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM email_tbl WHERE id=".$_GET['id']." LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the delete.php file:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "DELETE FROM email_tbl WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
```

and also check the section below:
You are running the query twice. so it is obvious it will add the same record twice.

```
$insertEmail = run_mysql_query($query);

if(run_mysql_query($query))
{
    $_SESSION['message'] .= "New RECORD has been added correctly!";
}
```

Modify you code to use the run_mysql_query once only.