# How do I delete a record in php MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

So I want to be able to delete a record in PHP using a button next to each row in the table. I cannot find a good tutorial anywhere that can help me with my problem and I am really stuck and don't know what to do.

Here is my code if someone can tell me what to do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PCSS Grad Gown</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Grad_Gown_Report.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>

<style>

  body {
      background-image: url("http://www.miguelmontalban.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/uSr9bZA-fancy-background-images.jpg");
  }

  td {
      color: white;
  }

  .Grad_Table {
      color :white;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $servername = "Private";
    $username = "Private";
    $password = "Private";
    $dbname = "Private";


    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    $order;
} 
   $order = $_GET['order'];
    if (!$order) {
        $order = "name";
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT * FROM Information ORDER By $order");

    ?>

    <div class="table-responsive" id="grad_table">

        <br>
        <br>

    <table class="Grad_Table" width="100%" border="12px">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="Grad_Gown_Report.php">Name:</a></td>
                <td><a href="Grad_Gown_Report_2.php">Student #:</a></td>
                <td>Homeform #:</td>
                <td>Unit:</td>
                <td>Height:</td>
                <td>Size:</td>
                <td></td>



            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php

            while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
            ?>

            <tr>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Studentnum'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Homeform'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Unit'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Height'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows['Size'];?></td>









            </tr>

            <?php


            }


            ?>
        </tbody>


    </table>

    </div>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can retrieve data from the database perfectly and everything else functions exactly how I want it. The only thing that I need is the delete function. I have tried many things, including the tutorial on W3 Schools, I tried the object oriented and procedural methods but they both give me the same error. I would really prefer a separate delete.php file, but I'm fine with anything that works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=delete+record+PHP

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP script that deletes entries by ID, then as you create your table rows, output a link to the script with the given ID.

```
// Using your code as a reference
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) : ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="/somepath/delete_entry.php?entry_id=<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>">Delete Entry</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
endwhile;
```

The delete script would look something like:

```
<?php
  // Perform any user auth here ...

  // Connect to mysql here ...

  if(!isset($_GET['entry_id'])) {
    die('You need to provide an ID');
  }

  $id = $_GET['entry_id'];

  // Ensure the ID is an integer or an int-like string
  if(!ctype_digit("$id")) {
    die('Invalid ID provided');
  }

  // We've verified that if $id is a string, it is an int-like string; otherwise, it is actually an integer.
  // Let's convert it to an actual integer
  $id = (int) $id;

  // At this point, if you have users and users own this resource, you might check to make sure they actually have permission to delete the requested resource.

  $query = "DELETE FROM Information WHERE Id = $id;";
  $mysqli->query($query);

  // If this is a rest API, you can just end with HTTP 200 (let the script die); 
  // otherwise, redirect them to the page they should see after performing this action
  header('location: /view_something.php');
```

---

You need to be careful though - I notice in your code that you're taking user input and inputting it directly into your SQL queries. This makes it easy to target your application with [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). One specially crafted HTTP request could delete your entire database, if an attacker so desired.

In simple terms, you need to validate and escape string input received from a user before putting it into a query, to ensure they don't add their own SQL that performs additional tasks under your application's authority.

As you're using `mysqli`, you'll want to check out [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

You might look up PDO / prepared statements, or perhaps adopt a framework that does all this for you automatically.

---

Finally: doing things the "vanilla PHP way" makes it very difficult to maintain and test your code. I encourage you to check out:

- Laravel (or any other modern PHP framework)
- REST APIs
- Object Oriented PHP Development
- PHP Composer

Comment: and how would I create that script that deletes entries by ID

Comment: @AsadKhan - Updated my answer

Comment: I don't know why but it still isn't working

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Have you modified my code to suit your application?

Comment: When I click the delete button, it brings me to the page where I set the ID of the die

Comment: Did you check the linked duplicate question above? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284554/delete-record-in-a-row-in-php?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, but none of them help me

Comment: At this point, it's probably best that take a step back and follow a few short beginner PHP guides that cover this stuff. I'd recommend that you learn the basics of the language and how to generate a simple HTML web app with some static data before trying to integrate a database into your application. Starting PHP and MySQL at the exact same time is going to make this a lot harder than it needs to be.

Comment: well, this is for school, and we don't really learn much in class so, what can you do. Although I am getting help from somewhere else now and it seems to be coming along, so thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate you taking time out of your day to help me solve my problems

Comment: You're very welcome. Best of luck with all this